# MockStore - not works as expected, throw error while test dispatch and subscribe

Tags: angular, angular8

Using mockstore, I am trying to do the test for my shell components dispatch and subscribe. But end with errors. looking for the help to fix this:

spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ShellSubSystemComponent } from './shell-sub-system.component';
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { ModelPFServices } from './../../../models';
import * as subsystemActions from './../../../state/actions/subSystem.action';
import { reducer } from './../../../state/reducers/reducer';
import * as subscribe from './../../../state';
import { SharedModule } from './../../../../shared-components/shared.module';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EffectsSubSystem } from './../../../state/effects/subSystem.effects';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('ShellSubSystemComponent', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShellSubSystemComponent>;
    let component: ShellSubSystemComponent;
    let store: MockStore<ModelPFServices>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ShellSubSystemComponent],
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                SharedModule,
                EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
            ],
            providers: [
                provideMockStore({
                    selectors: [{ 
                        selector: subscribe.getSubSystems, value: [] //providing the mock
                    }]
                })
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        })
        .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShellSubSystemComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        spyOn(store, 'dispatch');

    }));


    it('should dispatch an action to load data when created', () => {
        const action = new subsystemActions.LoadSubSystem();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);
    });

    it('should receive the subsytem from slicer', () => {
        const action = new subsystemActions.LoadSubSystemSuccess([]);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);
    });


});

getting error as:

    NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[EffectsFeatureModule -> StoreRootModule]:
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[EffectsFeatureModule -> StoreRootModule]:
        NullInjectorError: No provider for StoreRootModule!
```

[Full Version of Code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrcbcr)

**new Error:**

```
 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - LoadSubSystemSuccess {
    -   "payload": Array [],
    -   "type": "[SubSystem] LoadSubSystemSuccess",
    + LoadSubSystem {
    +   "type": "[SubSystem] LoadSubSystem",
      },

    Number of calls: 1

      52 |         const action = new subsystemActions.LoadSubSystemSuccess([]);
      53 |         fixture.detectChanges();
    > 54 |         expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);
         |                                ^
      55 |
      56 |     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the effects module if you're using the mockstore (the actions won't reach the effects/reducers anyway).

Thus, you can remove the line

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
```

Comment: I am getting an new error, can you please advice here? I am calling `LoadSubSystem` on init. once it called getting back-end response, and  effects called with `LoadSubSystemSuccess` - this is what i added in selector and trying

Comment: As a general, we are only testing the dispatches, not the pipes ( values subscribes from selector ) what is the reason? other than dispatch noting to test in container?

Comment: yea you're right because you just check the dispatch, you should not provide the effectsmodule

Comment: so, not require to test the `subscribe` -? if so why? for knowledge